Асинхронная загрузка Bitmap в Carousel
Я столкнулся с проблемой того, что я не могу понять, как загружать Bitmap асинхронно в Carousel в Avalonia. Если я правильно понял, то для этого нужно использовать ObservableCollection<> и в XAML использовать {Binding ...^} для того, чтобы указать на асинхронность выполнения.
Если для простого Image можно использовать Task<Bitmap> и все прекрасно работает, то Carousel представляет собой ItemControl и в него надо сувать коллекцию, но если я так делаю (вне зависимости от того простой это Bitmap или Task<Bitmap>), то компилятор выдает исключение (NRE).
Это абстрактный пример класса
private ObservableCollection<Task<Bitmap?>> _gallery;
private Task<Bitmap?> _poster;

var poster = Utility.LoadFromWeb("https://place.abh.ai/s3fs-public/placeholder/DSC_0089_400x400.JPG");;

Poster = poster;
Gallery = [poster, poster, poster];

А в XAML это выглядит как-то так
<Image ... Source="{Binding Poster^}"/>
<Carousel ... ItemsSource="{Binding Gallery^}"/>

Загрузчик фото выглядит стандартно (из примера документации)
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

try
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data));
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while downloading image '{url}' : {ex.Message}");
    return null;
}


Source это какой то IImage. Без понятия что это у авалонии, но в их ужасной доке есть такое замечание "You must reference Avalonia.Media.Imaging ... because you must use the Avalonia UI bitmap here, and not the .NET System.Bitmap."

@vitidev Кстати, в WPF такая же фигня - там тоже специальный вид картинки, который надо делать из битмапа. И думаю это неспроста.

А что такое Gallery - свойство? Если эта Avalonia что-то типа WPF, то для ObservableCollection не нужно делать свойство с извещением об изменении, ObservableCollection сама с этим прекрасно справляется при её изменениях, для этого она и придумана.

@CrazyElf так это ж ObservableCollection и есть...

@PavelMayorov Это _gallery - ObservableCollection , а что такое Gallery из приведённого кода можно только догадываться. Или в Avalonia такое само автоматом обвязывается?

using var httpClient = new HttpClient(); так не надо делать, об этом в документации HttpClient сказано. Клиент надо создавать один раз на всё время работы приложения.

"NRE" - Not Reproducible Exception?

@aepot -> NRE - null reference exception, про HttpClient - хорошо, учту, но это пример из документации самой Avalonia, я решил не изобретать велосипед.

@CrazyElf -> Gallery - это свойство, которое привязано к атрибуту ItemSource тега Carousel, а Poster - это свойство привязанное к атрибуту Source тега Image

@vitidev ->  я это видел, пример с Poster работает и все загружается, как локально, так и загрузка с веба, но когда дело доходит до асинхронной загрузки в Carousel коллекции Bitmap, то я сразу получаю исключение (это если убираю ^ в привязке), если оставить ^, то код даже не компилируется

Что такое Utility.LoadFromWeb? и где await?

@aepot, LoadFromWeb - это загрузчик фото, последний пример, await не нужен, потому что в Avalonia, когда ставишь привязку и указываешь, что она асинхронная (^) необходимо передавать именно Task, тогда все отлично работает, но почему-то в случае с множеством это не работает, или нужно что-то делать с ObservableCollection, или попробовать передать Task<List<Task>> (но это уже выглядит бредово), в документации Carousel про асинхронную загрузку ничего не сказано и в интернете не нашел ничего похожего

Ну тогда Gallery = Task.WhenAll(poster, poster, poster); при этом Task<Bitmap?[]>  _gallery тип будет

Всё оказалось проще, чем я думал. В частности, мои ошибки:

Я помещал в коллекцию не Image, а Bitmap (может, можно и Bitmap, я не проверял, потом отредактирую).
Мой парсер возвращал не прямую ссылку на фото, поэтому MemoryStream выдавал исключение (я думал это из-за асинхронности).
Для тега Image нужно ставить ^ для асинхронности, для Carousel в этом нет необходимости, потому что ObservableCollection и без этого справляется.

Пример для потомков (Avalonia + ReactiveUI):
Свойства, где хранится наша галерея:
private ObvservableCollection<Image> _gallery = [];
public ObservableCollection<Image> Gallery
{
    get => _gallery;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _gallery, value);
}

Последовательная загрузка:
var links = new List<string>() { "ссылка", "ссылка" };

foreach (var link in links)
{
    var image = new Image
    {
        Source = await Utility.LoadFromWeb(link)
    };

    Gallery.Add(image);
}    

Паралелльная загрузка:
var links = new List<string>() { "ссылка", "ссылка" };
var tasks = links.Select(async link => new Image { Source = await Utility.LoadFromWeb(link) });
var images = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Gallery = new ObservableCollection<Image>(images);

И все работает, код для загрузки изображения доступен выше.

Здесь вы последовательно грузите картинки, а я в комментарии вам предложил параллельно

@aepot, да, безусловно, это так. но моя проблема была все таки не про последовательно/паралелльно, а про загрузку в Carousel. Но как я понимаю, то предпочтительнее (с точки зрения загрузки) загружать параллельно?

Это на скорость влияет, ещё HTTP/2 включите у HttpClient - DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20, и если сервер поддерживает, то ещё подрастёт.

@aepot, благодарю, это хороший совет, сейчас подправлю свой ответ.

Если после загрузки картинок вы в коллекцию ничего не добавляете и не удаляете, то ObservableCollection - излишество, можно простым массивом обойтись. И кстати именно массив Task.WhenAll возвращает.
